# Yii2 assign values according to the previous ones

Tags: yii2

I have a `2 dropdown menus`, which is in my form. I have created 2 databases: `category` and `item`, their structure is below:

category database:
`id, name`

item database:
`id, category_id, name, price`.

I manually stored data inside of it (in the `category` I stored `Computers`, `Cars` and `Phones` and according to the categories id I manually stored items.

So I have 2 `dropDownMenus`, one is `category name` and the other is `item name`. Here is what I need to do:

If the user selects f.e `computer` categories, automatically `items` dropdownmenu should show computer items and so on. Could someone explain how it can be solved? I guess I should show that the item dropdown menu should show the values according to the `category_id`, but i'm not sure.

Here is my `view` file, where is those 2 dropdown menus:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'code') ?>
<?= $form->field($category, 'name')->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->All(),'id','name')) ?>
<?= $form->field($item, 'name')->dropDownList(
       ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->All(),'id', 'name')) ?>
```

I hope that you understand my problem, thanks for any help.

Comment: See [Kartik's DepDrop](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) extension for this.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to somehow just show in the item dropdown list that it would select automatically which values to show according to the previous selection?

Comment: This is exactly what this extension does.

Comment: Thank you again, Bizley, for the useful information!

Comment: One more question for you. I'm new to programming and especially Yii2, so if I want to use this extension, do I have to install in in composer or not?

Comment: Not necessarily but it's the easiest way.